# Android application two layouts and changing layout based on the spinner value

Tags: android-layout

I am new to android applications. I want to create  an application that should have a spinner in the beginning and based on the item selected in the spinner the lower design/layout/values changes. Basically there can be two layouts one in the upper half with spinners and the lower half will vary based on the spinner value. 
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use Fragments to achieve this thing. Have a look at below tutorial this will help you.

### http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html